# TypeError: update() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: javascript, python, flask-sqlalchemy, html

I am building a website using REST API with Flask-SQLALCHEMY.
I have been trying to add the Update for a specific API and it always tells me that it needs 2 arguments and i am giving it one.

Views.py code

```
    def patch(self, groupnumber):
    group_query = Group.query.filter_by(groupnumber=groupnumber)
    raw_dict = request.form
    try:
        schemaGroup.validate(raw_dict)
        for key, value in raw_dict.items():
            setattr(group_query, key, value)

        group_query.update()
        return self.get(userid)

    except ValidationError as err:
        resp = jsonify({"error": err.messages})
        resp.status_code = 401
        return resp

    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        db.session.rollback()
        resp = jsonify({"error": str(e)})
        resp.status_code = 401
        return resp
```

Models.py code

```
class Group(db.Model, CRUD):
__tablename__ = 'cowgroup'
cownumber = db.Column(db.Text)
groupnumber = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
groupname = db.Column(db.Text)
groupdescription = db.Column(db.Text)
attributes = db.Column(db.Text)
user = db.Column(db.Text)

def __init__(self, cownumber, groupnumber, groupname, groupdescription, attributes,user):
    self.cownumber = cownumber
    self.groupnumber = groupnumber
    self.groupname = groupname
    self.groupdescription = groupdescription
    self.attributes = str(attributes)
    self.user = user


class Group_Schema(Schema):
    not_blank = validate.Length(min=1, error='Field cannot be blank')
    id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)  # WHY DOES THIS HAVE TO BE HERE???
    cownumber = fields.String(validate=not_blank)
    groupnumber = fields.Integer(validate=not_blank)
    groupname = fields.String()
    groupdescription = fields.String()
    attributes = fields.String()
    user = fields.String()

    # self links
    def get_top_level_links(self, data, many):
        if many:
            self_link = "/group/"
        else:
            self_link = "/group/{}".format(data['attributes']['groupnumber'])
        return {"self": self_link}

    class Meta:
        type_ = 'group'
```

You can see the schema here for the data I'll be passing and I'll also put the data I'm passing through just below this.

```
"cownumber": "[\"365\",\"366\",\"367\"]",
"groupnumber": 1011,
"groupname": "Test1",
"user": "pk@gmail.com",
"attributes": "[\"pasturenumber\",\"sex\",\"breed\",\"height\",\"weight\",\"animaltype\",\"status\"]",
"groupdescription": "Test1"
```

Can somebody look into this and help me what I'm doing wrong.
I couldn't find any related topics which deals with update() either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs, [Query.update](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update) takes 1 mandatory positional argument, which should be a `dict` of the attributes to update.

You should update your code as following:

```
# ...
schemaGroup.validate(raw_dict)
group_query.update(raw_dict)
return self.get(userid)
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.
But i ended up with another error.

`(sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.`